# Change Value Properties in Object with Ramda Lenses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ramda.js

I would like to know how can I change object properties with Ramda Lenses.

Currently, I have a deep state :

```
buckets[
    blocks[
        messages[
            replies [
                {id: 0, text: 'text 0', value: 'simple value 0'},
                {id: 1, text: 'text 1', value: 'simple value 1'},
                {id: 2, text: 'text 2', value: 'simple value 2'},
                ...
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I have a basic payload. I would like to get the property and the value, and set the old value by the new value in my state, for example with this payload :

> {text: 'new_text'}
>   or
>   {value: 'new_value'}

In my reducer I have this :

```js
case SEQUENCES.UPDATE_REPLY_ON_BLOCK :
// payload => {text: 'new_text'}, or {value: 'new_value'}, or anyway...

let key = Object.keys(payload)[0];
let value = payload[key];

return R.over(
  R.lensPath(["buckets", 0, "blocks", 0, "messages", 0, "replies", 0, key]),
  R.set(value),
  state
);
```

I tried with Merge :

```
return R.over(
    R.lensPath(["buckets", 0, "blocks", 0, "messages", 0, "replies", 0),
    R.merge(payload),
    state,
);
```

But same result : the state is not modified and I have no error.

> Maybe SOLVED with mergeDeepLeft :

```
//payload => {value: 'new_value'}

return R.over(
    R.lensPath(["buckets", 0, "blocks", 0, "messages", 0, "replies", 0),
    R.mergeDeepLeft(payload),
    state,
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close.  The problem is that [`R.set`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#set) and [`R.over`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over) are used for two different tasks.  You don't need `over` here.  Instead your outer function should be `set` and the second parameter the value you want to set the lens to:

```js
const payload = {text: 'new_text'}
const key = Object.keys(payload)[0];
const value = payload[key];

const state = {buckets: [{blocks: [{messages: [{replies: [{id: 0, text: 'text 0', value: 'simple value 0'}, {id: 1, text: 'text 1', value: 'simple value 1'}, {id: 2, text: 'text 2', value: 'simple value 2'}]}]}]}]}

console.log(
    R.set(
        R.lensPath(['buckets', 0, 'blocks', 0, 'messages', 0, 'replies', 0, key]),
        value,
        state,
    )
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

You use `over` when you want to adjust it based on the value that's already there, passing a function from old value to new value as the second parameter. For instance, `R.over(myLens, R.toUpper, obj)`:

```js
const payload = {text: 'new_text'}
const key = Object.keys(payload)[0];
const value = payload[key];

const state = {buckets: [{blocks: [{messages: [{replies: [{id: 0, text: 'text 0', value: 'simple value 0'}, {id: 1, text: 'text 1', value: 'simple value 1'}, {id: 2, text: 'text 2', value: 'simple value 2'}]}]}]}]}

console.log(
    R.over(
        R.lensPath(['buckets', 0, 'blocks', 0, 'messages', 0, 'replies', 0, key]),
        R.toUpper,
        state,
    )
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott for you answer ! Use mergeDeepLeft is better ?

Comment: Your `mergeDeepLeft` is quite appropriate, so long as you want everything in your payload included.  Obviously, it's still cleaner code, since you don't have to extract your key and value.  The important thing to understand here is what `set` and `over` are used for.